# How can a malicious seccomp filter cause an attempt to use `setuid(2)` to return 0, without actually making the system call?

Tags: debian, security, setuid, seccomp

I was reading the documentation on `seccomp(2)` on my Debian system, and stumbled upon the following sentence from the paragraph below:

> Such a malicious  filter  might,  for  example,  cause  an  attempt 
>   to  use `setuid(2)`  to  set the caller's user IDs to non-zero values
>   to instead return 0 without actually making the system call.

How can `seccomp` filters be abused to achieve what's described above?

If the malicious filter disallows `setuid(2)`, then the process will likely receive a `SIGSYS` signal and terminate and the syscall won't be executed.

If the malicious filter allows `setuid(2)`, then the `execve(2)`'d program will correctly change the UIDs of the user.

What am I missing?

`man seccomp`:

> ...
>
> Otherwise,  the  SECCOMP_SET_MODE_FILTER  operation  will  fail  and
>   return EACCES in errno.  This requirement ensures that an unprivileged
>   process cannot apply a malicious filter and then
>                 invoke a set-user-ID or other privileged program using `execve(2)`, thus potentially compromising that program.  (Such a
>   malicious  filter  might,  for  example,  cause  an  attempt  to  use
>                 `setuid(2)`  to  set the caller's user IDs to non-zero values to instead return 0 without actually making the system call. 
>   Thus, the program might be tricked into retaining superuser privi‐
>                 leges in circumstances where it is possible to influence it to do dangerous things because it did not actually drop
>   privileges.)
>
> ...

Comment: I think the important part is "This requirement ensures that an unprivileged process cannot..."

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor That actually doesn't explain it. The seccomp code is part of the system call.

Comment: I think it is using "system call" to mean "run the intended code". Not to mean "call into the kernel". So while it is true that you are running kernel code, you don't get to run the `setuid` code.